# iPhone + Android App to view Blog

Tags: iphone, android, blogs

What would be the best way to write an app for the iPhone OS and the Android OS that allows access to a web blog (posted on blogspot.com)? Are there ways to manipulate the incoming data from the website to fit the UI of the phones, or will I have to re-do a lot of the blogs?

Any help would be nice! And thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best bet is to use [Phonegap open source framework](http://www.phonegap.com/).

Since it basically creates local webapps and both platforms have very similar browser capabilities this should be a good fit for your intended application.

Comment: i'm trying to sort through this, and please correct me if i'm wrong in stating my next question:

developing with this will allow me "re-route" the html coding and merge it with the UI's of the specific OS's?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in both would be to integrate the browser in the web app but perhaps restrict it to the blog.

For example, your app would open and have its own UI, but displaying the actual blog content would be done in an integrated browser (such as a WebView in Android).

Doing it this way isn't the best as it wouldn't be the best experience for the user, but it has the added benefit of keeping all the blog's design and extras, as well as javascript functionality.

"Manipulating incoming data from the website" (otherwise known as scraping) would be tricky for modern blogs since they usually contain so much customised content and are nowadays more like websites with blogs than just regular blogs.